# How to get calculation in float when we divide the two array's integers in C++;

Tags: c++, floating-point

I need to solve a problem below in which I need to print final result as a `float`,
but this code gives the output as an `int` value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;

    for(int i=0; i<T; i++)
        {
            int N;
            cin>>N;
            int  A[N],B[N];
            float K=0;

                for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                    cin>>A[i];

                 for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                    cin>>B[i];

                 for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                     K=(B[i]/A[i]) +  K ;

                     cout<<K<<endl;
        }
    return 0;    
}
```

**Input:**
1
2
4 2
10 6

**Output:** 
 6 
**Desired output:** 
 5.500000

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150773/discussion-on-question-by-mayur-birle-how-to-get-calculation-in-float-when-we-di).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need type cast one of the values of the calculation to be a `(float)` for the result to be a `float` value:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    for(int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        int  A[N], B[N];
        float K = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cin >> A[j];

        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cin >> B[j];

        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
             K += (float)B[j] / A[j];

        cout << K << endl;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: One cast is enough. No need to cast both operands. Also, static_cast is preferred in C++.

Comment: @SergeyA Un-needed force of habit.

Comment: It's not that the **result** should be a float; you could do that by simply casting the result itself. It's that the **calculation** should be done with floats, which is why you cast at least one of the **values**.

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah that was a typo

Comment: @MayurBirle Does this give you the same result?

Comment: @AlexG Yes, This gives the same output as previous (i.e  6).

Comment: Found the error.  Its an error in your code :P. Fixed.

Comment: @MayurBirle in the final for loop you had `i`(s) instead of `j`(s) causing it to act funky.

Comment: @AlexG Yes,second and third for loop has wrong variables .Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

With some C++14 trickery you can simplify your computation to:

```
float K = std::inner_product(begin(B), end(B), begin(A), 0.0f, std::plus<float>{}, std::divides<float>{});
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/odVOlceNaZCTvGAP)

Also note that dynamic arrays are a GCC extension, so the following code is not portable:

```
int N;
cin>>N;
int  A[N],B[N];
```

We can use a simple `vector` instead (I did it for the code snippet above):

```
    vector<int> A, B;
    int tmp;

    for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
        cin >> tmp;
        A.push_back(tmp);
    }

    for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
        cin >> tmp;
        B.push_back(tmp);
    }
```

#### Explanation:

[`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) is primarily meant for... well, computing the inner product (sum of pairwise multiplications) on two collections. However, it parameterizes both the "sum" aspect and the "product" aspect, so we can sub out the "product" for a "division". The C++14 [`std::divides`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/divides) and [`std::plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) function objects make it easier for us to specify the operations we want (else we could write a lambda for C++11).